# Declare custom tag filter in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Am trying to declare a custom function with 2 parameters but it isn't working as expected ,
am getting this error :

```
Invalid block tag on line 4: 'original|get_customer_by_status:'CONFIRMATION_PENDING'', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

This is my template code :

```
{% original|get_customer_by_status:'CONFIRMATION_PENDING' as customer_pending_loan %}
```

Then my custom tag filter :

```
@register.filter
def get_customer_by_status(queryset, status):
    print(queryset)
    print(status)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `with` template tag:

```
{% with customer_pending_loan=original|get_customer_by_status:'CONFIRMATION_PENDING' %}
    your code here where you need to use customer_pending_load variable
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, just got the solution.